# How get sps struct from h264 video with libav ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, h.264, decoder, libav

For my HW decoder I need know additional codec specification about video codec like h264? How I can extract low level codec info with libav ffmpeg?

The data that I need:  https://www.ffmpeg.org/doxygen/2.7/structSPS.html

Comment: Yes, I need get codec info and them parse to CUDA video decoder.

Answer (score 1):

You can either look at each NALU in the stream looking for an SPS ( nalu[0] & 0x1F == 7 ) or you can take a look at the AVCC data pointed to by AVCodecContext.extradata and parse it as described here:

http://aviadr1.blogspot.com/2010/05/h264-extradata-partially-explained-for.html